# Powerline Font not working in iTerm 2

Tags: terminal, iterm2

I'm trying to use [Prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) on OS X with iTerm 2. I have the patched powerline font installed on my system, and I'm using the patched powerline font, but my prompt is still not being displayed correctly. [image]

My locale settings are all utf-8:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I'm just not sure how to fix this. I use the same patched font setup on linux with the Terminator terminal and tmux, and I don't have any problems. Is there something else I have to do for iTerm?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to use the theme `agnoster`,  set `12pt Meslo LG S DZ Regular for Powerline` for `Non-ASCII Font`.